# MySQL Query To Select Rows Where Column Has Both of 2 Values in Entire Result Set

Tags: mysql

I have single a table that contains IP data from a number of websites I run in which I use a column SiteCode to identify what data originates from what website like this:

```
ID    SiteCode    IP            Page
--    --------    --            ----
1     BHS         192.168.1.1   index.php
2     ED          192.168.4.4   index.php
3     BHS         192.168.1.1   index.php
4     ED          192.168.1.1   index.php
```

What I am trying to do, is figure out how I can select only those IP numbers which have SiteCodes in rows for both (not either) BHS and ED in the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM `ip-tracking` WHERE `IP`='192.168.1.1' ?????
```

I hope I have been clear.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using condtional aggregation while grouping on each IP address you can check to make sure that an IP is associated with both types of site code:

```
SELECT IP
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY IP
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN SiteCode = 'BHS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN SiteCode = 'ED'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

If `BHS` and `ED` are the only two site codes which ever appear in the table, then the `HAVING` clause can be simplified to:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SiteCode) = 2
```

Comment: Remarkably fast response there Tim, Thank you. I am not at my MySQL server at the moment, but I will test asap and come back to you.